# Accessing winform control with System.Threading.Task gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library

The new Task class works great in WPF. However in Winforms, it is always stuck every time it tries to access a Winform control. The "InvokeRequired" routine below that has been working with BackgroundWorker and Thread classes that prevents cross-thread operation error. However, for some reason when it comes to Task, it gets stuck on the **Invoke** method. Help ?

Here is a sample code. I use NET 4.5.1 framework.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinformTaskDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Task t = new Task(() => { setText(now); });
            t.Start();
            t.Wait();
        }

        private void setText(string text)
        {
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = text)); //stuck forever here
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change this value 
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
This will now allow change the textbox value in both threads
or red this article how to Thread safe calls
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I tried the solution from MSDN link, it does not work. Control.Invoke is still stuck. CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls workaround works, but I would not be able to use it.

Comment: Ok try using this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're deadlocking yourself. You run a task but synchronously block on it using `Task.Wait()`. This operation blocks the UI thread. Now, from a background thread, you synchronously post a message to the same UI message loop you just blocked. Hence, a deadlock.

The solution to this would be not to block the `Task`, but asynchronously wait on it. Though question does come to mind, if you're only interacting with UI elements, why do it in a background thread in the first place?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
     await Task.Run(() => { setText(now); });
}
```

Comment: This is the solution. Glad to know async works for winform events too.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an assumption why it stucks there forever but
your task waits in the button1.clicked method which is a GUI related method.

Your action wants to access the UI thread then and is blocked because your task is waiting.

I tried it like this to see if it will jump back into the debugger but it doesn't

```
private void setText(string text)
{
    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Action callSetText = () => setText(text);
        textBox1.Invoke(callSetText);

    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

I tried that for myself a time ago and you can't block the UI thread and then Jump back into it in WinForms

So you will have to remove the `t.Wait()`
Why do you use it there ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the statement lock to prevent change a object value in both threads at the same time.

```
    lock(textBox1){
      //Change here the textbox value
      textBox1.Text = "ok";
    }
```

This will lock and wait when a already other thread is using the same object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're locking the UI thread with the t.Wait()

if you remove that, the action will complete. You are causing a race condition in that the Wait is waiting for the text to set and the text cant set because the Wait is happening.

Comment it out and you will see. If you need something to happen once t has completed, you can do it with

```
        t.ContinueWith(_ => { finished()); });
```